# How to access App components with Jest when using Redux container?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am having some trouble testing components inside App because I am only exporting AppContainer.

```js
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

const AppContainer = () => (
  <Provider store={clearanceStore}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>
);

export default AppContainer;
```

How do I test components inside App's return()? This is what I have for a test now which gives an error: Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

```js
test('setSubmit triggered when clicking submit button', () => {
    const setSubmit = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    const button = wrapper.find('#something');
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(setSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: try `mount` instead of `shallow` https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html

Comment: Tried already, does not work. Do I have to use dive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Redux documentation that should help you:

> In a unit test, you would normally import the App component like this:

```
import App from './App'
```

> However, when you import it, you're actually holding the wrapper component returned by connect(), and not the App component itself. If you want to test its interaction with Redux, this is good news: you can wrap it in a  with a store created specifically for this unit test. But sometimes you want to test just the rendering of the component, without a Redux store.
>
> In order to be able to test the App component itself without having to deal with the decorator, we recommend you to also export the undecorated component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

// Use named export for unconnected component (for tests)
export class App extends Component {
  /* ... */
}

// Use default export for the connected component (for app)
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

> Since the default export is still the decorated component, the import statement pictured above will work as before so you won't have to change your application code. However, you can now import the undecorated App components in your test file like this:

```
// Note the curly braces: grab the named export instead of default export
import { App } from './App'
```

> And if you need both:

```
import ConnectedApp, { App } from './App'
```

More at https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests